# Phpmyadmin gives meaningless syntax error for trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I'm trying to add a trigger to my database however I get an "not meaningful" syntax error from mysql.

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_balance_table AFTER INSERT ON _explorer.transfers

FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
        /* TO*/
      INSERT INTO _explorer.balances (account, balance) VALUES (new.account, new._to) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = balance + new._quantity;
        /* FROM*/
      UPDATE _explorer.balances SET balance = balance - new._quantity  WHERE account = new._from;
  END
```

Comment: You don't appear to have set delimiters.Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: thanks, I'm using phpmyadmin and the delimiter is set to ; My statements are also separated by ; so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Change phpmyadmin delimiter to something else ($$ seem the most common) create your trigger and then reset the delimiter to ; BTW it would have been useful if you had mentioned phpmyadmin in your question.